# React Context error: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<GiftsType>>' is not assignable to type '(arr1: string[], arr2: string[]) => void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-context

I'm trying to create a context in React+TS, which takes 2 string arrays and updates an object's state with these arrays. But I'm getting the title typo error in setChoices  inside return statement and I'm not able to solve it. Could you guys help me, please?

Code:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

type GiftsType = {
  choices: string[];
  links: string[];
  setChoices: (arr1: string[], arr2: string[]) => void;
};

export const GiftsContext = createContext<GiftsType>({
  choices: [],
  links: [],
  setChoices: (arr1, arr2): void => {},
});

export function GiftsProvider({ children }) {
  const [gifts, setGifts] = useState<GiftsType>({
    choices: [],
    links: [],
    setChoices: (arr1, arr2) => void {},
  });

  return <GiftsContext.Provider value={{ ...gifts, setGifts }}>{children}</GiftsContext.Provider>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
type GiftsType = {
  choices: string[];
  links: string[];
  setChoices: (arr1: string[], arr2: string[]) => void;
  setGifts: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<GiftsType>>
};
```

it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here :

```
export function GiftsProvider({ children }) {
  const [choices, setChoices] = useState<GiftsType>({
    choices: [],
    links: [],
    setChoices: (arr1: string[], arr2: string[]) => void {}, // change the name
  });

  return <GiftsContext.Provider value={{ ...choices, setChoices }}> {children}</GiftsContext.Provider>;
}
```

You're using the same name as your state setter function and in the value that you are using spread operator you'll have two setChoices which is wrong.

Comment: Hi, Eisa! Thanks for answering. I did change the variables naming, but still getting an error: 


Type '{ setGifts: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<GiftsType>>; choices: string[]; links: string[]; setChoices: (arr1: string[], arr2: string[]) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'GiftsType'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'setGifts' does not exist in type 'GiftsType'.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GiftType` needs the `setGift` function.

The value you're giving the provider is essentially

```
{
  choices: string[]
  links: string[]
  setChoices: (arr1: string[], arr2: string[]) => void
  setGifts: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<GiftsType>>
};
```

But it's expecting

```
{
  choices: string[]
  links: string[]
  setChoices: (arr1: string[], arr2: string[]) => void
};
```

Simply amend your GiftType (Type in the name is redundant, you could just name the type `Gift`) to include this function